# How to combine if/else in PHP string inderection

Tags: php

i build long strings like this :  ( how do you call it in php ?))

```
$json = <<< JSON
{
   "campaign": {
    "name": "$campaign_name",
    "state": "$state",
    "advertiser_id": $advertiser_id,
    "line": $line,
    "daily_budget": $daily_impression,
    "pacing": $pacing_selected,
    "cpm_type": "$bittype"
    }
}
JSON;
```

all the variables are set befor with values but now i need to add logic and check 
if for example $campaign_name is not empty and if it is empty dont add in this string indirection the string :

```
 "name": "$campaign_name",
```

the same for the other variables . 
how can i do this inside this string builder ?

Comment: Just do it above the string.

Comment: Don't build JSON by hand. Use `json_encode` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the logic outside and just include a variable

```
$campaign_name_JSON = "";
if (!empty($campaign_name))
   $campaign_name_JSON = '"name": "'.$campaign_name.'",';

$json = <<< JSON
{
   "campaign": {
    $campaign_name_JSON
    "state": "$state",
    "advertiser_id": $advertiser_id,
    "line": $line,
    "daily_budget": $daily_impression,
    "pacing": $pacing_selected,
    "cpm_type": "$bittype"
    }
}
JSON;
```

But you are much better off building the data structure in php then json_encoding it

Answer (score 6):

**Don't write JSON by hand.** It's just a recipe for disaster. Make the array first, then convert it to JSON.

```
$data = array();

if( !empty( $campaign_name ) ) {
    $data[ "name" ] = $campaign_name;
}
// you might want to make a better system than checking each variable individually,
// but this is the general idea

$json = json_encode( array( "campaign" => $data ) );
```